# Isolating The Difference Between Windows 7 and Windows XP Shutdown Procedures

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I'm having some trouble with a program I'm developing behaving differently between Windows 7 Professional SP1 and Windows XP Professional SP3 upon shutdown. It should prompt the user to save when shutting down, similar to Excel. Excel works in Windows 7 and XP, but my program only works in 7.

I've tried using

```
taskkill /im process.exe
```

just for my process and

```
taskkill /im explorer.exe /t
```

for the explorer tree in attempt to isolate the issue, but my program acts as intended. Does anybody have any insight to how the shutdown procedure works in terms of how it kills processes? Are there any differences between Windows XP and Windows 7?

Comment: This is better left to Stackoverflow.  Post a new question with the code you use to subscribe to the event that handles when a process is killed.  There are many differences between how Windows XP and Windows 7 handles shutting down your computer far to many to list.

Comment: I posted this exact question on Stackoverflow and I was told to come here. I'm trying to look at this from a high perspective. I'm asking if there is a way of replicating this from a high level that an end user could even reproduce.

Comment: I didn't cross post; I deleted my post on Stackoverflow after posting this one. If it's not suitable for this, I'll just delete this post as well and continue searching elsewhere.

Comment: Well then it can stay here I guess :)